# Why doesn't Heroku like my folder structure?

Tags: python, github, heroku, bots, discord

So this [Discord Bot](https://github.com/glmn/PUBGDiscoBot) works perfectly fine when I run it lokal on my PC. But when I push it to Heroku i get the following error log. 
When I try to delete *"Styles"* (the part mentioned in the log down below) in the `render.py` the Bot goes online but is not working (of course).

```
heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command python src/main.py
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[worker.1]:   File "src/main.py", line 9, in <module>
app[worker.1]:     from render import RenderStats
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/src/render.py", line 6, in <module>
app[worker.1]:     class RenderStats():
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/src/render.py", line 29, in RenderStats
app[worker.1]:     'titles': ImageFont.truetype("fonts/MyriadPro-Bold.otf", 10),
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 546, in truetype
app[worker.1]:     return freetype(font)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 543, in freetype
app[worker.1]:     return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 161, in init
app[worker.1]:     font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine=layout_engine
app[worker.1]: OSError: cannot open resource
```

Is the folder structure the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku isn't made for hosting Discord Bots, but to answer your question the issue might be Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). As Heroku explains [here](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) you may host static files (such as fonts) dedicated, they might get deleted upon Herokus daily [cycling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).